# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when run a snapshot test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying a snapshot test and i am getting this error. I Have no idea why i am getting this error.Please help me to solve this issue

**test**

```
test('Snapshot test for the Login form', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Login {...props} />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

**error**

● Snapshot test for the Login form

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Which version of Jest are you using? This post on SO says this is caused by a bug in Jest which was fixed in version 22.0.4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326879/1253156

Comment: i am using  "jest": "22.4.3",